# Laravel Middleware Too few arguments to function error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to setup a middleware to check if inputs are empty on form submit for updating a users settings, and if so to return them back to the same page with an error. When I set it up, it gives me the error

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Middleware\AdminUserUpdate::handle(), 2 passed in /var/www/market/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php on line 167 and exactly 3 expected
```

It seems to be the id I pass through, here is the rest of my code

Middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $id)
    {
        if($request->input('username') == NULL) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.members.view', $id)->with('error', 'You must enter a username for this user in order to update their account!');
        } elseif($request->input('email') == NULL) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.members.view', $id)->with('error', 'You must enter a email for this user in order to update their account!');
        } elseif($request->input('admin') == NULL) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.members.view', $id)->with('error', 'You must select whether this user is a root admin or not in order to update their account!');
        } elseif($request->input('banned') == NULL) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.members.view', $id)->with('error', 'You must select whether this user is banned or not in order to update their account!');
        } elseif($request->input('role') == NULL) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.members.view', $id)->with('error', 'You must select a role for this user in order to update their account!');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Kernel:

```
'AdminUserUpdate' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminUserUpdate::class,
```

Route:

```
Route::middleware(['AdminUserUpdate'])->group(function () {
        Route::post('/app/members/{id}/submit', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Members\IndexController@Submit')->name('admin.members.submit'); 
    });
```

I have the ID passed through so I can return them back to the view page for the specific users id, but it doesnt seem to like that for some reason. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Middlewares doesn't read route parameters. Use colon to pass a parameter to the middleware.

```php
Route::middleware(['AdminUserUpdate:123'])->group(function () {
```

[Link to Middleware Parameters docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-parameters)

Comment: How exactly would that work with my view page for each user ID?

Comment: Instead of using a middleware, add your validation/redirection at the start of your controller method.

Comment: Yeah that's what I usually do but wanted the controller function to be short and clean - guess that's not an option with how I am trying to do it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change the way you validate your fields.

In your case, this command create the form validator file

```
php artisan make:request UpdateUserRequest
```

In the file UpdateUserRequest.php

This block have all the rules you want to validate

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        ... other fields for validation ...
    ];
}
```

and inside the `store` method in your Controller, only this line is required to manipulate all the data after the validation:

`$validated = $request->validated();`

and for custom messages, add this into your `UpdateUserRequest`:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'username.required' => 'You must enter a username for this user in order to update their account!',
        'email.required' => 'You must enter a email for this user in order to update their account!',
        ... and other validation messages ...
    ];
}
```

For more details and ways to validate your forms, check the link:

[Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation)